# Estimate the cost of gas in Truffle Console?

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-deployment

Is there a way in the Truffle console to estimate the cost of gas for deploying a contract to mainnet?

I'm attempting to `truffle migrate --network main` a contract, and it's running out of gas.

I've been tweaking the `gas` and `gasPrice` in truffle-config.

```
// truffle-config.js
main: {
      network_id: 1, // Main's id
      gas: <gas limit>,
      gasPrice: <gas price>
```

But it would be very helpful to know what the gas would be to deploy a specific contract.

Comment: Try the following in truffle console: `ContractName.new.estimateGas()`

Answer (score 1):

@alberto has it correct.

```
truffle(ropsten)> Migrations.new.estimateGas()
193243
```

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can estimate with Truffle this way bellow:

**P.S: You most have the last version of Truffle installed globally that uses Ganache with gas exactimation.**

Example of contract

```
// ./contracts/ContractFactory.sol
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract ContractFactory {
  function createInstance() public {
    new Contract();
  }
}

contract Contract {
  constructor() public {}
}
```

Test the gas estimate:

```
// ./test/ContractFactory.js
const ContractFactory = artifacts.require("ContractFactory");

contract("ContractFactory", () => {
  it("...should deploy and successfully call createInstance using the method's provided gas estimate", async () => {
    const contractFactoryInstance = await ContractFactory.new();

    const gasEstimate = await contractFactoryInstance.createInstance.estimateGas();

    const tx = await contractFactoryInstance.createInstance({
      gas: gasEstimate
    });
    assert(tx);
  });
});
```

Run the test command

```
$ truffle test
...
...
Contract: ContractFactory

✓ ...should deploy and successfully call createInstance using the method's provided gas estimate (130ms)

1 passing (143ms)
```

You can to do if gas is exactimation, subtract exactly a single unit of gas from the gasEstimate before sending our test transaction.

```
// ./test/ContractFactory.js
const ContractFactory = artifacts.require("ContractFactory");

contract("ContractFactory", () => {
  it("...should deploy and successfully call createInstance using the method's provided gas estimate", async () => {
    const contractFactoryInstance = await ContractFactory.new();

const gasEstimate = await contractFactoryInstance.createInstance.estimateGas();

const tx = await contractFactoryInstance.createInstance({
      gas: gasEstimate - 1 // subtract
    });
    assert(tx);
  });
});
```

Test result

```
$ truffle test
...
...
Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
```

Comment: Why do you need all this if you can use Migrations.new.estimateGas()?